# Losing context in knockout component

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin, knockout-3.0, knockout-components

I am packaging a component as a single AMD module using requirejs following this example: https://github.com/sumitkm/BuildingSpaUsingKO/tree/Part2

The problem is when adding a click event when it calls that function in the viewmodel the self property does not contain the viewmodel and points it to window. What is causing this issue?  Btw if they are loaded without requirejs and they are inline this issue is not happening.

[image]

Index.html:

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Dipping your feet into KnockoutJS Components</title>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">KO Components</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content" style="padding-top:50px">
        <h2>Dipping your feet into KnockoutJS Components</h2>
        <hr />
        <greeter params='name: " Sumit!"'></greeter>
        <greeter params='name: " Optimus!"'></greeter>
        <greeter params='name: " Bumblebee!"'></greeter>
    </div>
    <footer class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p> &copy; 2014 - Still Learning</p>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="App/boot/require.config.js"></script>
    <script data-main="App/boot/startup" src="Scripts/require/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

require.config.js

```
var require = {
baseUrl: "/",
paths: {
    "bootstrap": "Scripts/bootstrap/bootstrap",
    "jquery": "Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.9.0",
    "knockout": "Scripts/knockout/knockout-3.2.0beta.debug",
    "text": "Scripts/require/text"
},
shim: {
    "bootstrap": {
        deps: ["jquery"]
    }
}
}
```

startup.js

define(['jquery', 'knockout', 'bootstrap'], function ($, ko) {

```
    ko.components.register('greeter', { require: 'App/components/greeter/greeting' });


    ko.applyBindings();
});
```

greeting.html - component template

```
 <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div> Hello <span data-bind='text: greeting'></span></div>
    <div> It is <span data-bind='text: date'></span></div>

    <input type="button" value="test" data-bind="click: testClick" />
  </div>
```

greeting.js - component viewmodel

define(["knockout", "text!./greeting.html"], function (ko, greeterTemplate) {

```
    function greeterViewModel(params) {
        var self = this;
        self.greeting = ko.observable(params.name);
        self.date = ko.observable(new Date());

        self.testClick = function () {
            //self is pointing to window instead of greeterViewModel
            debugger;
        };
    }
    return { viewModel: greeterViewModel, template: greeterTemplate };
});
```

Comment: can you post the full code and html

Comment: Added the needed code to reproduce the issue. Btw the code is on github the only change is adding a click function into the component viewmodel and using that in the component template.

Comment: mmh - you're not passing any viewmodel to ko.applyBindings(), not sure if this would work... try putting at least an empty literal {}

Comment: I have a more complex example where i pass a viewmodel into the applybindigs function it still have the same issue. That's how i found the issue. I tried just putting empty literal just to be sure, it still doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: Another issue I've noticed as well is you reference knockout both in your html and requirejs. You should remove the <script> reference to ko in the html if you are using requirejs. same for bootstrap and jquery

Comment: That is commented out i will remove the comments now so it can clearer at least for knockout because the issue is not connected with bootstrap at all.

Comment: Have you tried using a knockout version different from beta?

Comment: In the more complex solution i am using the 3.3.0 version which is the latest production version and i still have the same issue.

Comment: What does your click binding receive as its first argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JavaScript compiler tries to be smart about closures. Because your function doesn't use any variables from the closure, the function simply doesn't include the closure. Change your code to this and you'll see that it works:

```
    self.testClick = function () {
        console.log(self);
        debugger;
    };
```

Comment: Really strange i know i tried the console.log stuff yesterday and couldn't get the viewmodel context. This morning when i tried putting the console.log the context from the viewmodel was there. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Strange indeed! I certainly can't explain that.